# Поворот группы объектов в SVG по оси Y

Tags: svg, css-animation

Не получается достигнуть результата, чтобы при наведении курсора на изображение синий щит (сторона .front) вращался по оси Y, и видно было красный щит (сторона .back)

```html
<svg class="logo" aria-labelledby="logo" focusable="false" data-name="_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g class="flipper">
      <g class="front">
        <path d="m78.98,18.47v13.91c0,13.91-14.49,34.79-28.98,45.22-14.49-10.44-28.98-31.31-28.98-45.22v-13.91c9.66,0,24.15-6.96,28.98-10.44,4.83,3.48,19.32,10.44,28.98,10.44Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m77.26,19.92v13.09c0,13.09-13.63,32.72-27.26,42.54-13.63-9.82-27.26-29.45-27.26-42.54v-13.09c9.09,0,22.72-6.54,27.26-9.82,4.54,3.27,18.17,9.82,27.26,9.82Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
        <path d="m75.46,21.47v12.23c0,12.23-12.73,30.57-25.46,39.73-12.73-9.17-25.47-27.51-25.47-39.73v-12.23c8.49,0,21.22-6.11,25.47-9.17,4.24,3.06,16.98,9.17,25.46,9.17h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <g>
          <text transform="translate(30.68 40.63)" style="fill: #fff; font-family: Garamond, Garamond; font-size: 28.68px; isolation: isolate;"><tspan x="0" y="0">АА</tspan></text>
        </g>
        <g>
          <text transform="translate(40.39 60.89)" style="fill: #fff; font-family: Garamond, Garamond; font-size: 28.68px; isolation: isolate;"><tspan x="0" y="0">Л</tspan></text>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="back">
        <path d="m78.98,18.47v13.91c0,13.91-14.49,34.79-28.98,45.22-14.49-10.44-28.98-31.31-28.98-45.22v-13.91c9.66,0,24.15-6.96,28.98-10.44,4.83,3.48,19.32,10.44,28.98,10.44Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m77.26,19.92v13.09c0,13.09-13.63,32.72-27.26,42.54-13.63-9.82-27.26-29.45-27.26-42.54v-13.09c9.09,0,22.72-6.54,27.26-9.82,4.54,3.27,18.17,9.82,27.26,9.82Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
        <path d="m75.46,21.47v12.23c0,12.23-12.73,30.57-25.46,39.73-12.73-9.17-25.47-27.51-25.47-39.73v-12.23c8.49,0,21.22-6.11,25.47-9.17,4.24,3.06,16.98,9.17,25.46,9.17h0Z" style="fill: #b22222;"/>
        <path d="m70.78,38.1c.79,1.59,1.48,3.22,2.35,4.77-1.14,1.09-2.45,2.03-3.92,2.64-1.21.51-2.51.79-3.82.89-1.15,0-2.32.02-3.44-.27-1.3-.26-2.52-.81-3.65-1.48-.85-.51-1.62-1.14-2.3-1.87.13-.08.27-.16.35-.29.27-.4.43-.86.66-1.29,1.36-2.87,2.63-5.79,3.97-8.67.45-.96.84-1.95,1.3-2.91.47-1.04.94-2.07,1.41-3.11.15-.36.35-.71.45-1.1-1.33.27-2.65.55-3.98.79-1.54.33-3.09.62-4.58,1.12-1.06.35-2.1.79-3.02,1.44-.76.5-1.4,1.19-1.83,2-.06.09-.06.2-.06.31,0,2.84,0,5.67,0,8.51-.05,5.2-.03,10.41-.04,15.61,0,.13,0,.26.07.38.55-.3,1.09-.62,1.67-.86-.52,1.33-1.15,2.61-1.72,3.92-.24.47-.38.98-.7,1.41-.24-.3-.38-.67-.54-1.02-.63-1.43-1.32-2.84-1.88-4.29.58.24,1.11.58,1.68.85.04-2.24.01-4.47.06-6.71,0-1.77,0-3.53,0-5.3-.07-4.14.01-8.28-.05-12.41.02-.39-.22-.71-.42-1.02-.38-.52-.85-.98-1.38-1.35-2.09-1.36-4.56-1.95-6.97-2.45-1.57-.29-3.13-.6-4.69-.93.02.09.03.19.07.27,2.02,4.52,4.1,9.02,6.13,13.55.46,1,.89,2.01,1.38,2.99.11.23.26.43.45.61-.12.25-.35.4-.54.59-1.48,1.37-3.35,2.28-5.31,2.73-.81.23-1.67.27-2.51.25-.6.02-1.19-.03-1.79-.07-2.55-.37-5-1.57-6.77-3.46,0-.22.17-.4.25-.59,1.54-3.17,2.98-6.39,4.44-9.6.4-.96.85-1.91,1.28-2.86.7-1.56,1.4-3.12,2.1-4.68-.51-.29-1.06-.64-1.22-1.24-.24-.73.36-1.53,1.1-1.59.41-.03.82.13,1.12.4.2.22.23.54.36.8.31.66.93,1.11,1.58,1.42,1.53.73,3.24,1,4.92,1.08-.19.02-.38.04-.57.06,1.22-.07,2.45.06,3.67.17.57.05,1.12.19,1.65.38.61.25,1.16.63,1.67,1.05.01-.42.06-.84.04-1.26.02-.11-.05-.2-.11-.29-.59-.82-1.2-1.63-1.81-2.45,0-2.49-.02-4.99.01-7.48,0-.26.02-.52.05-.78.63.76,1.21,1.57,1.82,2.35.03-1.06.04-2.12.06-3.17.43-.12.89-.04,1.33-.04.02,1.07.03,2.15.06,3.22.64-.76,1.18-1.6,1.83-2.35.05.96.03,1.93.04,2.89.01,1.69.02,3.38,0,5.08.01.18-.06.34-.16.48-.48.71-1,1.39-1.51,2.08-.12.17-.28.33-.25.56.01.39-.03.79.05,1.17.81-.68,1.79-1.17,2.83-1.33,1.26-.2,2.55-.2,3.82-.31,1-.1,2.01-.21,2.99-.46.95-.22,1.88-.58,2.64-1.2.32-.26.59-.6.71-1,.09-.24.12-.52.32-.69.38-.35.93-.41,1.42-.3.29.09.52.32.66.58.24.49.14,1.1-.18,1.54-.26.29-.63.45-.94.67,1.21,2.87,2.52,5.69,3.79,8.53.67,1.48,1.35,2.96,2.03,4.44Zm1.49,4.55c-.39-1.11-.92-2.17-1.38-3.25-2.08-4.58-4.14-9.17-6.28-13.73-.58,1.16-1.08,2.35-1.63,3.53-1.41,3.09-2.8,6.19-4.22,9.29-.6,1.39-1.26,2.75-1.83,4.15,1.31.07,2.63.04,3.95.05,2.37,0,4.73.02,7.1-.02,1.43-.01,2.86.02,4.29-.02Zm-20.45-19.15c.15-.21.14-.48.13-.72-.21.08-.32.29-.46.46-.27.38-.58.74-.81,1.15-.11.17-.1.37-.05.55.1.03.15-.09.22-.15.34-.42.67-.85.96-1.29Zm.02-3.65c.16-.21.1-.49.09-.74-.45.51-.83,1.07-1.22,1.63-.18.22-.11.51-.1.76.42-.55.84-1.09,1.23-1.66Zm-.01,1.86c.18-.24.13-.56.09-.84-.41.48-.75,1.02-1.12,1.53-.18.23-.2.53-.11.8.42-.46.78-.98,1.15-1.49Zm-.1-3.45c.25-.28.24-.67.17-1.01-.41.46-.77.96-1.11,1.47-.19.26-.23.58-.19.9.47-.36.75-.91,1.13-1.36Zm-1.67-1.48c.16-.49.07-1.01.09-1.51-.13.01-.27.04-.39.09-.02.42-.04.84,0,1.25.01.15.19.15.3.17Zm-.8,2.81c0-.33.01-.69-.2-.97-.35-.5-.71-1-1.12-1.45,0,.34-.07.72.14,1.01.27.41.61.75.87,1.16.08.1.14.26.3.25Zm0,3.52c-.01-.2.04-.42-.03-.61-.18-.28-.39-.53-.59-.8-.23-.27-.41-.57-.68-.8-.02.27-.08.59.1.82.24.33.49.66.73.99.13.16.24.37.47.39Zm0,1.94c.02-.31.01-.64-.18-.9-.34-.48-.69-.97-1.1-1.39-.09.24-.12.52.05.72.39.53.74,1.12,1.23,1.57Zm-.03-3.58c0-.27.07-.57-.1-.81-.35-.54-.76-1.04-1.17-1.54-.02.23-.06.48.07.69.33.6.82,1.09,1.2,1.66Zm-6.31,21.18c-.05-.17-.11-.34-.18-.51-1.82-4.15-3.7-8.27-5.59-12.39-.62-1.33-1.21-2.68-1.88-3.99-.69,1.36-1.31,2.75-1.94,4.14-1.61,3.54-3.22,7.08-4.84,10.61-.27.61-.57,1.21-.8,1.83-.03.09-.03.19-.04.29,3.04.05,6.07.03,9.11.04,2.05,0,4.1.02,6.16-.02Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
      </g>
    </g>

    <g class="laurel">
      <g>
        <path d="m90.72,34.64c.38,2.6.41,5.24-.44,7.74-.82,1.99,1.08,3.87.41,5.85-.57,3.27-2.6,5.98-4.89,8.25.3-1.18.89-3.54,1.19-4.73-.76,1.2-1.41,2.46-2.18,3.65-.16-.64-.48-1.91-.65-2.55-.34,1.2.62,3.6-1.5,3.38-.18,2.22-.55,4.41-.94,6.6-.04.24-.09.48-.13.73-.84.08-2.5.25-3.33.34.47-3.55.85-7.52,3.87-9.88-.36-2.85-.23-5.81,1.32-8.3.8,1.58,1.52,3.21,2.21,4.85.96-1.37,1.99-2.71,2.83-4.16-.6-1.95-1.2-3.91-1.4-5.96-2.93-2.16-4-5.79-3.33-9.35.74.64,1.48,1.28,2.21,1.92.02-2.81.16-5.61.62-8.39,3.25,2.81,2.95,7.48,2.36,11.34-.55-.99-1.07-2-1.58-3.01.08,1.8.07,3.61.13,5.41,1.09-1.23,2.13-2.51,3.23-3.74h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m89.84,54.51c-.7,4.26-3.16,8.36-7.3,9.94.75-1.26,1.53-2.5,2.33-3.72-.72.54-2.17,1.62-2.89,2.16.5-2.58,2.01-4.66,3.98-6.2,1.17-.92,2.5-1.64,3.88-2.17Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m87.35,46.09l-1.34-.15-.4,1.86c-2.25-2.65-2.86-6.19-2.24-9.57,2.35,1.97,3.53,4.86,3.97,7.86h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m86.65,64.02c-1.38,4.52-5.82,6.82-10.12,7.52.86-1.07,1.75-2.12,2.6-3.2-1.89.86-3.51,2.17-5.05,3.57.16-.95.48-2.84.65-3.79-.61,1.38-1.24,2.76-1.9,4.13-.96-4.58.79-9.27,4.07-12.42.56,2.71.65,5.49.07,8.23,2.55-2.67,6.05-3.98,9.68-4.02h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m69.7,75.62c3.12-2.81,7.34-3.31,11.32-2.7-2.26,4-6.92,6.09-11.35,4.91,1.15-.75,2.33-1.47,3.52-2.13-.87-.02-2.63-.06-3.5-.08h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m72.46,67.76c-.5,4.21-2.3,8.66-6.45,10.34.51-1.01,1.54-3.04,2.05-4.05l-3.77,3.69c1.24-4.27,3.62-8.72,8.17-9.98h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m62.62,80.46c3.14-3.38,7.7-2.06,11.28-.35-2.46,2.29-6.03,3.91-9.31,2.66-1.16-1.05,1.03-1.3,1.74-1.48-1.24-.29-2.48-.57-3.71-.84h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m63.8,82.77l1.92,1.81c-3.08,1.67-7.16,2.66-10-.03.87-.23,2.6-.69,3.47-.93-1.3-.32-2.59-.67-3.87-1.05,2.55-2.01,5.64-.67,8.48-.41-.24.51-.74,1.55-.98,2.06l.99-1.46Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m65.42,72.74c-.8,3-2.25,5.75-3.91,8.34-1-1.64-2.23-1.88-3.7-.72,1.56-3.32,3.47-7.28,7.6-7.63Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m53.71,79.79c2.76,1.49,1.04,5.22,1.14,7.69-2.22-1.91-.97-5.17-1.14-7.69Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m52.79,81.79c0,1.23-.02,2.45-.08,3.68-.8,1.1-2.07,1.67-3.14,2.47-.13-.69-.4-2.07-.53-2.76-.23.72-.71,2.17-.95,2.9-1.15-2.66-1.43-5.75.27-8.24.14,1.49.28,2.99.4,4.48,1.01-1.01.46-2.82.79-4.14,1.08.54,2.16,1.07,3.24,1.6Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m46.16,79.67c.29,2.76.29,5.56-.13,8.31-.39-.98-.74-1.98-1.04-2.99-2.21.53-4.39,1.58-6.7,1.3-1.46-.35-2.76-1.13-4.09-1.81.87-.51,1.75-1.03,2.62-1.54-3.85.58-7.95.19-10.83-2.75,2.37-.83,4.77-2.01,7.34-1.81,1.39.48,2.7,1.16,4.01,1.8-1.11.34-2.22.67-3.33.99,3.41,2.08,7.14-.89,10.53,1.17.51-.9,1.04-1.8,1.62-2.66h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m41.92,79.71c-1.44-.27-2.48.28-3.14,1.65-1.99-2.59-3.55-5.5-4.13-8.77,3.63.77,5.74,3.98,7.27,7.11h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m35.54,77.58c-.62-.51-1.87-1.52-2.49-2.04-.17.28-.52.83-.7,1.1-.22.05-.67.15-.9.2-2.37-2.38-3.66-5.66-3.73-9.03,4.35,1.36,6.58,5.64,7.82,9.77h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m30.62,78.1c-2.55-.11-5.36.36-7.69-.97-1.63-1.09-2.76-2.76-3.96-4.29,4.18-.41,8.81-.04,11.65,3.56-1.11-.08-3.33-.22-4.44-.29,1.49.63,2.97,1.3,4.44,2h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
        <path d="m22.91,60c3.91,2.81,4.83,8.01,4.21,12.57-.62-1.54-1.23-3.1-1.8-4.67.09,1.11.27,3.33.36,4.43-.98-1.18-1.94-2.37-2.9-3.56.05.71.17,2.12.22,2.83-3.9-.87-7.66-2.87-9.55-6.62.55-.33,1.64-.99,2.19-1.31-3.13-2.01-4.77-5.42-5.52-8.98,1.24.58,2.5,1.15,3.76,1.64,1.49,1.58,2.76,3.35,4,5.12-.03-2.84-.46-5.79-3.4-6.77-.57-.98-1.05-2.01-1.49-3.06-.06.63-.17,1.89-.23,2.52-.22.13-.64.38-.85.51-1.61-3.08-3.17-6.36-2.76-9.97,2.01,1.62,3.62,3.64,5.1,5.76.36-.61.71-1.22,1.05-1.85-.86-1.09-1.68-2.23-2.6-3.27-2.26.25-2.81-2.22-3.33-3.91-.63-2.25-.28-4.61-.03-6.89,2.34,2.3,3.3,5.5,4.11,8.6.51-1.06,1.02-2.12,1.53-3.16-.84-.66-1.69-1.31-2.46-2.06-.22-1.57-.07-3.15.17-4.7-.42.66-1.27,2-1.68,2.66-.21-2.61-.63-5.33.17-7.9.36-1.08.58-2.61,2-2.61.86,2.44.89,5.07.97,7.64.5-.49,1.5-1.45,2-1.94.12,2.14,0,4.28-.49,6.37,1.68,3.11,1.33,6.71-.51,9.67.52-.24,1.58-.72,2.11-.95,1,3.15.11,6.46.8,9.63l1.19-1.05c1.25,2.87,2.12,5.91,2.33,9.05-.47-.03-1.42-.09-1.88-.13-.86-.34-2.6-1.03-3.46-1.37.97,3.24,4.81,3.46,6.75,5.92-.39-2.72-.39-5.48-.12-8.21h0Z" style="fill: #072531;"/>
      </g>
    </g>
<defs>
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
.logo {
    perspective: 100px;
}

/* переворот стороны при наведении курсора мыши */
.logo:hover .flipper, .logo.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
 
.logo, .front, .back {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
.flipper {
    transition: 0.9s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: center;
}
 
/* скрывает обратную сторону во время переворота */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
 
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
 
/* обратная, изначально скрытая сторона */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
    ]]></style>
</defs>

</svg>
```

**Вариант №2** вынужденно удалён, т.к. для размещения 3-го не хватает символов

**Вариант №3**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>LOGO</title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="_logo_" class="logo" data-name=" logo " aria-labelledby="logo" focusable="false" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100px" height="100px" x="0px" y="0px">

    <g class="flip-container" id="_flip-container_" data-name=" flip-container ">
      <g class="flipper" id="_flipper_" data-name=" flipper ">
        <g class="front" id="_front_" data-name=" front ">
          <path id="_blue-shield-big_" data-name=" blue-shield-big " d="m78.98,18.47v13.91c0,13.91-14.49,34.79-28.98,45.22-14.49-10.44-28.98-31.31-28.98-45.22v-13.91c9.66,0,24.15-6.96,28.98-10.44,4.83,3.48,19.32,10.44,28.98,10.44Z" style="fill: #1f3047;"/>
          <path id="_white-shield-front_" data-name=" white-shield-front " d="m77.26,19.92v13.09c0,13.09-13.63,32.72-27.26,42.54-13.63-9.82-27.26-29.45-27.26-42.54v-13.09c9.09,0,22.72-6.54,27.26-9.82,4.54,3.27,18.17,9.82,27.26,9.82Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
          <path id="_blue-shield-small_" data-name=" blue-shield-small " d="m75.46,21.47v12.23c0,12.23-12.73,30.57-25.46,39.73-12.73-9.17-25.47-27.51-25.47-39.73v-12.23c8.49,0,21.22-6.11,25.47-9.17,4.24,3.06,16.98,9.17,25.46,9.17h0Z" style="fill: #1f3047;"/>
          <text id="_letters_" data-name=" letters " transform="translate(32.53 39.26)" style="fill: #fff; font-family: AGaramondPro-Regular, &apos;Adobe Garamond Pro&apos;; font-size: 28px;"><tspan x="0" y="0">AA</tspan></text>
          <text transform="translate(59.45 41.75) rotate(180)" style="fill: #fff; font-family: AGaramondPro-Regular, &apos;Adobe Garamond Pro&apos;; font-size: 28px; letter-spacing: -.43em;"><tspan x="0" y="0">V</tspan></text>
        </g>
        <g class="back" id="_back_" data-name=" back ">
          <path id="_blue-shield_" data-name=" blue-shield " d="m78.98,18.47v13.91c0,13.91-14.49,34.79-28.98,45.22-14.49-10.44-28.98-31.31-28.98-45.22v-13.91c9.66,0,24.15-6.96,28.98-10.44,4.83,3.48,19.32,10.44,28.98,10.44Z" style="fill: #1f3047;"/>
          <path id="_white-shield-back_" data-name=" white-shield-back " d="m77.26,19.92v13.09c0,13.09-13.63,32.72-27.26,42.54-13.63-9.82-27.26-29.45-27.26-42.54v-13.09c9.09,0,22.72-6.54,27.26-9.82,4.54,3.27,18.17,9.82,27.26,9.82Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
          <path id="_red-shield_" data-name=" red-shield " d="m75.46,21.47v12.23c0,12.23-12.73,30.57-25.46,39.73-12.73-9.17-25.47-27.51-25.47-39.73v-12.23c8.49,0,21.22-6.11,25.47-9.17,4.24,3.06,16.98,9.17,25.46,9.17h0Z" style="fill: #b22222;"/>
          <path id="_arrow-scale_" data-name=" arrow-scale " d="m70.78,38.1c.79,1.59,1.48,3.22,2.35,4.77-1.14,1.09-2.45,2.03-3.92,2.64-1.21.51-2.51.79-3.82.89-1.15,0-2.32.02-3.44-.27-1.3-.26-2.52-.81-3.65-1.48-.85-.51-1.62-1.14-2.3-1.87.13-.08.27-.16.35-.29.27-.4.43-.86.66-1.29,1.36-2.87,2.63-5.79,3.97-8.67.45-.96.84-1.95,1.3-2.91.47-1.04.94-2.07,1.41-3.11.15-.36.35-.71.45-1.1-1.33.27-2.65.55-3.98.79-1.54.33-3.09.62-4.58,1.12-1.06.35-2.1.79-3.02,1.44-.76.5-1.4,1.19-1.83,2-.06.09-.06.2-.06.31v8.51c-.05,5.2-.03,10.41-.04,15.61,0,.13,0,.26.07.38.55-.3,1.09-.62,1.67-.86-.52,1.33-1.15,2.61-1.72,3.92-.24.47-.38.98-.7,1.41-.24-.3-.38-.67-.54-1.02-.63-1.43-1.32-2.84-1.88-4.29.58.24,1.11.58,1.68.85.04-2.24,0-4.47.06-6.71v-5.3c-.07-4.14,0-8.28-.05-12.41.02-.39-.22-.71-.42-1.02-.38-.52-.85-.98-1.38-1.35-2.09-1.36-4.56-1.95-6.97-2.45-1.57-.29-3.13-.6-4.69-.93.02.09.03.19.07.27,2.02,4.52,4.1,9.02,6.13,13.55.46,1,.89,2.01,1.38,2.99.11.23.26.43.45.61-.12.25-.35.4-.54.59-1.48,1.37-3.35,2.28-5.31,2.73-.81.23-1.67.27-2.51.25-.6.02-1.19-.03-1.79-.07-2.55-.37-5-1.57-6.77-3.46,0-.22.17-.4.25-.59,1.54-3.17,2.98-6.39,4.44-9.6.4-.96.85-1.91,1.28-2.86.7-1.56,1.4-3.12,2.1-4.68-.51-.29-1.06-.64-1.22-1.24-.24-.73.36-1.53,1.1-1.59.41-.03.82.13,1.12.4.2.22.23.54.36.8.31.66.93,1.11,1.58,1.42,1.53.73,3.24,1,4.92,1.08-.19.02-.38.04-.57.06,1.22-.07,2.45.06,3.67.17.57.05,1.12.19,1.65.38.61.25,1.16.63,1.67,1.05,0-.42.06-.84.04-1.26.02-.11-.05-.2-.11-.29-.59-.82-1.2-1.63-1.81-2.45,0-2.49-.02-4.99,0-7.48,0-.26.02-.52.05-.78.63.76,1.21,1.57,1.82,2.35.03-1.06.04-2.12.06-3.17.43-.12.89-.04,1.33-.04.02,1.07.03,2.15.06,3.22.64-.76,1.18-1.6,1.83-2.35.05.96.03,1.93.04,2.89,0,1.69.02,3.38,0,5.08,0,.18-.06.34-.16.48-.48.71-1,1.39-1.51,2.08-.12.17-.28.33-.25.56,0,.39-.03.79.05,1.17.81-.68,1.79-1.17,2.83-1.33,1.26-.2,2.55-.2,3.82-.31,1-.1,2.01-.21,2.99-.46.95-.22,1.88-.58,2.64-1.2.32-.26.59-.6.71-1,.09-.24.12-.52.32-.69.38-.35.93-.41,1.42-.3.29.09.52.32.66.58.24.49.14,1.1-.18,1.54-.26.29-.63.45-.94.67,1.21,2.87,2.52,5.69,3.79,8.53.67,1.48,1.35,2.96,2.03,4.44l.02-.05s.01,0,.01,0Zm1.49,4.55c-.39-1.11-.92-2.17-1.38-3.25-2.08-4.58-4.14-9.17-6.28-13.73-.58,1.16-1.08,2.35-1.63,3.53-1.41,3.09-2.8,6.19-4.22,9.29-.6,1.39-1.26,2.75-1.83,4.15,1.31.07,2.63.04,3.95.05,2.37,0,4.73.02,7.1-.02,1.43,0,2.86.02,4.29-.02Zm-20.45-19.15c.15-.21.14-.48.13-.72-.21.08-.32.29-.46.46-.27.38-.58.74-.81,1.15-.11.17-.1.37-.05.55.1.03.15-.09.22-.15.34-.42.67-.85.96-1.29h0Zm.02-3.65c.16-.21.1-.49.09-.74-.45.51-.83,1.07-1.22,1.63-.18.22-.11.51-.1.76.42-.55.84-1.09,1.23-1.66h0Zm0,1.86c.18-.24.13-.56.09-.84-.41.48-.75,1.02-1.12,1.53-.18.23-.2.53-.11.8.42-.46.78-.98,1.15-1.49h-.01Zm-.1-3.45c.25-.28.24-.67.17-1.01-.41.46-.77.96-1.11,1.47-.19.26-.23.58-.19.9.47-.36.75-.91,1.13-1.36Zm-1.67-1.48c.16-.49.07-1.01.09-1.51-.13.01-.27.04-.39.09-.02.42-.04.84,0,1.25,0,.15.19.15.3.17Zm-.8,2.81c0-.33,0-.69-.2-.97-.35-.5-.71-1-1.12-1.45,0,.34-.07.72.14,1.01.27.41.61.75.87,1.16.08.1.14.26.3.25h.01Zm0,3.52c0-.2.04-.42-.03-.61-.18-.28-.39-.53-.59-.8-.23-.27-.41-.57-.68-.8-.02.27-.08.59.1.82.24.33.49.66.73.99.13.16.24.37.47.39h0Zm0,1.94c.02-.31,0-.64-.18-.9-.34-.48-.69-.97-1.1-1.39-.09.24-.12.52.05.72.39.53.74,1.12,1.23,1.57Zm-.03-3.58c0-.27.07-.57-.1-.81-.35-.54-.76-1.04-1.17-1.54-.02.23-.06.48.07.69.33.6.82,1.09,1.2,1.66Zm-6.31,21.18c-.05-.17-.11-.34-.18-.51-1.82-4.15-3.7-8.27-5.59-12.39-.62-1.33-1.21-2.68-1.88-3.99-.69,1.36-1.31,2.75-1.94,4.14-1.61,3.54-3.22,7.08-4.84,10.61-.27.61-.57,1.21-.8,1.83-.03.09-.03.19-.04.29,3.04.05,6.07.03,9.11.04,2.05,0,4.1.02,6.16-.02Z" style="fill: #fff;"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="laurell">
      <path d="m13.4,22.83c.49.53.69,1.25.86,1.94.46,2.01.35,4.1.32,6.15.59-.5,1.01-1.26,1.76-1.52.5.9.54,1.99.48,3-.2,1.91-.96,3.74-2.1,5.24-.16.19-.3.46-.57.49-.22-.76.03-1.53.2-2.27-.49.29-.44,1.08-.99,1.32-.17-2.28-.2-4.57-.38-6.85-.23.26-.17.64-.2.96,0,.85-.03,1.76-.5,2.49-.06,0-.17,0-.22,0-.54-1.64-.65-3.4-.65-5.13,0-1.35.22-2.73.86-3.92.35-.64.73-1.27,1.1-1.9Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m85.27,24.35c.15-.57.39-1.12.74-1.59.69,1.13,1.47,2.25,1.76,3.58.33,1.49.28,3.04.14,4.56-.07.79-.2,1.57-.39,2.33-.05.22-.16.42-.31.59-.81-1.14-.4-2.63-.73-3.92-.12,1.16-.13,2.33-.2,3.49-.11,1.26-.06,2.54-.24,3.8-.4-.33-.45-.93-.88-1.22.13.72.32,1.46.1,2.18-.54-.47-.93-1.1-1.3-1.71-1.01-1.79-1.63-3.93-1.26-6.01.09-.38.16-.82.46-1.1.7.35,1.18,1.02,1.71,1.59-.03-2.19-.17-4.43.41-6.57Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m10.31,32.84c1.34,1.13,2.15,2.81,2.73,4.47.58,1.81.72,3.81.26,5.67-.65-.11-.44-1.08-.94-1.4.05.7.2,1.4.07,2.1-.2.06-.32-.13-.43-.26-.38-.47-.65-1.01-.91-1.56-.5-1.06-1-2.12-1.27-3.27-.5-1.91-.15-3.94.5-5.76Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m88.87,32.96c.09-.08.21-.1.32-.14.35,1.26.71,2.55.67,3.88.05,1.26-.38,2.46-.82,3.61-.4.95-.83,1.89-1.38,2.76-.16.26-.38.48-.64.62-.13-.7-.01-1.4.04-2.1-.13.08-.24.18-.27.34-.14.4-.27.82-.58,1.11-.54-1.73-.4-3.61.06-5.34.51-1.76,1.34-3.45,2.61-4.74Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m16.82,36.86c.11-.06.23.04.23.17.33,1.39.52,2.86.19,4.27-.32,1.27-.92,2.45-1.66,3.5-.23.32-.53.58-.85.8-.19-.64-.06-1.3.05-1.93-.3.29-.48.68-.76.99-.22-.33-.21-.75-.26-1.13-.25-1.91.45-3.86,1.59-5.34.42-.51.87-1.04,1.46-1.32Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m82.47,36.83c.29-.06.53.19.75.36,1.29,1.15,2.17,2.81,2.43,4.56.08.95.11,1.94-.19,2.85-.34-.29-.47-.77-.83-1.04.11.62.28,1.25.14,1.87-.16.08-.31-.08-.42-.17-.61-.59-1.03-1.36-1.43-2.11-.7-1.32-1.04-2.87-.85-4.38.08-.65.15-1.33.4-1.93Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m10.03,43.26c.39.01.71.29,1.02.51,1.61,1.31,2.91,3.04,3.77,4.97.23-.3.35-.66.44-1.03.21-.87.56-1.69.96-2.48.21-.41.44-.81.77-1.13.38.25.55.73.76,1.13,1.01,2.17.88,4.7.34,6.98,1.36.61,2.33,1.92,2.84,3.35.69,1.91.88,3.98.79,6.01-.04.21.02.52-.21.62-.69-.55-.83-1.5-1.15-2.29-.06-.04-.17-.11-.23-.15.09.83.37,1.62.39,2.46-.93-.38-1.56-1.28-1.93-2.22-.57-1.41-.67-2.97-.7-4.48-.02-.87.08-1.73.04-2.6-.37.58-.48,1.36-1.07,1.77-.45-1.25-.13-2.59-.16-3.88-.26.28-.23.7-.32,1.05-.15.7-.22,1.42-.46,2.09-.61-.87-1.13-1.81-1.69-2.72-.1-.18-.25-.32-.43-.4.3,1.09.94,2.12.83,3.3-.41-.25-.73-.63-1.06-.98-.99-1.09-1.93-2.26-2.55-3.63-.8-1.65-1.12-3.52-1.07-5.35.01-.3,0-.61.09-.91Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m87.91,44.1c.42-.35.84-.73,1.36-.9.24.03.16.35.21.53.12,2.07-.25,4.19-1.19,6.02-.57,1.08-1.29,2.08-2.1,2.98-.44.48-.86.97-1.37,1.36-.15-1.25.6-2.33.9-3.48-.31.14-.46.46-.63.75-.37.66-.78,1.31-1.18,1.96-.12.2-.28.37-.46.51-.17-.75-.29-1.51-.44-2.26-.02-.18-.1-.32-.25-.4,0,.86.08,1.73.02,2.6-.02.31-.12.6-.25.87-.51-.36-.56-1.09-1.02-1.49-.05,1.57.11,3.16-.14,4.72-.18,1.15-.49,2.33-1.19,3.26-.34.45-.77.85-1.3,1.04.04-.97.41-1.88.47-2.84-.31.16-.3.56-.42.85-.22.66-.42,1.38-.93,1.87-.29.24-.28-.26-.3-.45-.1-2.27.11-4.63,1.05-6.71.53-1.18,1.44-2.16,2.55-2.74-.27-1.35-.51-2.72-.37-4.11.13-1.36.49-2.75,1.3-3.84.13-.22.36,0,.45.14.53.71.87,1.54,1.18,2.37.24.67.32,1.42.71,2.02.77-1.77,1.92-3.34,3.3-4.63Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m11.15,53.03c.51.07.99.27,1.45.49,2.21,1.02,4.12,2.86,5.09,5.2.28.74.55,1.51.52,2.31-1.21-.52-1.77-1.88-2.85-2.59.14.55.62.88.94,1.31.62.79,1.42,1.6,1.37,2.71-1.67-.62-3.09-1.84-4.22-3.26-1.35-1.74-2.22-3.92-2.31-6.17Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m87,53.38c.41-.19.83-.37,1.29-.38-.18,3.89-2.62,7.48-5.94,9.16-.19.1-.39.14-.6.18.02-.52.16-1.03.46-1.45.45-.65.94-1.28,1.49-1.85.14-.13.19-.31.24-.49-.41.15-.66.55-.95.87-.53.57-1.02,1.27-1.78,1.5.05-1.42.65-2.75,1.4-3.9,1.11-1.6,2.64-2.89,4.39-3.64Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m74.17,59.98c.52-.63,1.12-1.24,1.89-1.52.26.62.31,1.31.39,1.97.13,1.48.13,2.99-.15,4.46-.09.57-.27,1.13-.39,1.69.29-.11.43-.4.61-.64.97-1.33,2.35-2.29,3.83-2.88,1.53-.59,3.2-.85,4.81-.51-.07.31-.19.59-.33.87-.34.7-.64,1.43-1.1,2.06-1.1,1.57-2.77,2.6-4.53,3.16-1.09.34-2.22.62-3.36.69.1-.37.19-.78.46-1.06.45-.49,1.08-.7,1.61-1.06.15-.06.18-.23.24-.37-.86.22-1.62.72-2.47,1-.01-.09-.03-.28-.05-.38-.17.16-.3.36-.41.57-.39.7-.88,1.35-1.51,1.84-.14.13-.33.16-.51.18.15-1.01.41-2,.49-3.02-.32.08-.34.45-.44.72-.19.54-.27,1.12-.54,1.62-.18.27-.41.54-.73.64-.15-.68-.1-1.37-.11-2.06.04-1.73.18-3.48.71-5.12.34-1.05.91-2,1.58-2.85Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m23.33,58.57c.32.06.62.18.87.4.83.68,1.48,1.57,2.02,2.52.92,1.58,1.13,3.46,1.3,5.26.02,1.12.08,2.24-.06,3.35-.44-.2-.8-.59-.94-1.07-.13-.46-.24-.92-.39-1.37-.1-.27-.14-.6-.42-.74.03,1.1.4,2.16.48,3.26-.66-.26-1.14-.82-1.57-1.39-.32-.42-.5-.94-.85-1.33,0,.11-.02.34-.03.46-.89-.31-1.71-.83-2.62-1.07.23.49.79.63,1.2.91.63.29,1.16.87,1.22,1.6-.41.08-.82-.05-1.23-.11-2.09-.39-4.22-1.13-5.78-2.7-1.1-1.04-1.72-2.5-2.31-3.9.82-.22,1.69-.15,2.53-.11,2.27.29,4.48,1.4,5.97,3.23.26.31.42.72.77.94-.05-.55-.26-1.07-.35-1.62-.4-2.15-.37-4.4.17-6.52Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m27.88,66.39c1.56-.03,3.01.84,4.07,1.98,1.74,1.9,2.79,4.39,3.3,6.94-.37.05-.87.08-1.1-.3-.35-.59-.76-1.13-1.18-1.65-.09-.11-.21-.19-.33-.28.22,1.05,1.01,1.85,1.29,2.88-1.34-.16-2.51-1.02-3.35-2.08-1.24-1.56-1.95-3.5-2.39-5.45-.14-.67-.27-1.34-.31-2.03Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m67.77,68.01c.97-.92,2.2-1.62,3.52-1.7.34-.07.25.33.23.54-.27,1.81-.74,3.61-1.56,5.23-.71,1.37-1.69,2.68-3.06,3.37-.43.24-.91.39-1.4.4.26-.86.92-1.55,1.07-2.45-.57.29-.86.94-1.22,1.45-.2.44-.72.41-1.11.44.02-.64.23-1.25.41-1.86.64-2.02,1.63-3.96,3.12-5.43Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m19.71,71.03c1.24-.32,2.53-.32,3.8-.28,1.72.14,3.48.57,4.9,1.65.55.44,1.05.96,1.41,1.58.17.29.35.6.35.95-1.13-.2-2.22-.62-3.35-.8.11.36.51.4.8.52.68.25,1.42.42,1.97.91.29.26.47.63.53,1.03-1.96.03-3.98-.08-5.84-.78-1.41-.53-2.6-1.55-3.55-2.74-.46-.61-.9-1.26-1.04-2.04Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m71.81,71.83c1.83-1.02,3.95-1.25,5.99-1.15.66.04,1.32.1,1.96.31-.53,1.62-1.7,2.93-3.02,3.9-1.66,1.17-3.7,1.52-5.66,1.61-.6.03-1.2.09-1.79,0,.12-.37.28-.75.57-1,.66-.59,1.54-.73,2.33-1.05.17-.03.24-.19.29-.33-1.1.16-2.15.59-3.26.74.38-1.35,1.43-2.38,2.59-3.02Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m34.91,71.11c1.79.12,3.51,1.08,4.6,2.58.67.92,1.12,1.99,1.59,3.03.29.72.63,1.43.71,2.21-.28-.03-.6.02-.82-.19-.38-.34-.63-.81-1-1.17-.1-.13-.27-.12-.41-.17.13.46.42.84.67,1.23.2.29.39.61.68.82.38.2.81.21,1.23.28.94.13,1.74.7,2.5,1.25-.72.68-1.79.54-2.65.86-.03.05-.09.14-.13.19.96,0,1.93-.17,2.88.05.03-1.15-.08-2.32.13-3.46.02-.16.1-.3.26-.34.34-.05.69,0,1.02.07.16.62.15,1.26.2,1.89.06,1.52.02,3.05-.09,4.57-.01.15-.05.31-.13.44-.39.05-.8.06-1.19.01-.24-.72-.04-1.51-.21-2.25-.29.06-.58.16-.84.3-1.27.62-2.56,1.28-3.97,1.42-1.86.22-3.74-.59-5.07-1.91-.17-.1-.06-.29.04-.41.41-.47.93-.81,1.44-1.15.17-.1.29-.26.38-.44-.21.03-.42.08-.62.15-2.01.75-4.27.77-6.27.01-1.04-.39-1.96-1.12-2.59-2.06-.13-.2-.2-.43-.26-.65.9-.42,1.79-.86,2.71-1.21,1.7-.61,3.64-.73,5.31.03.74.33,1.46.81,1.88,1.54.04.07.1.27-.04.25-.94.17-1.91.06-2.85.24l.13.17c.62.24,1.3.13,1.95.22.44.05.88.31,1.06.76-.03.12-.1.35-.13.47.25-.05.49-.13.73-.24.67-.3,1.37-.5,2.04-.79,0-.36-.36-.45-.61-.61-.89-.48-1.61-1.25-2.2-2.08-1.04-1.53-1.59-3.36-1.96-5.18-.05-.25-.06-.5-.06-.75Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m60.18,73.3c.94-1.12,2.24-1.88,3.64-2.17.25-.05.51-.05.77-.04-.28,1.86-.79,3.73-1.73,5.35-.63,1.06-1.47,2.01-2.53,2.61-.25.16-.6.25-.66.6.59.25,1.21.44,1.8.69.4.16.78.41,1.23.42-.11-.16-.27-.29-.34-.48.09-.45.53-.75.94-.79.65-.12,1.32-.06,1.97-.19.15,0,.21-.14.27-.26-.86-.03-1.72-.13-2.58-.15-.14-.02-.33.02-.42-.13.12-.45.47-.76.8-1.05.95-.75,2.13-1.13,3.31-1.21,1.2-.05,2.41.2,3.53.67.79.33,1.59.67,2.34,1.1-.52,1.26-1.62,2.16-2.83,2.63-1.46.61-3.07.69-4.62.47-.73-.09-1.42-.38-2.13-.54.05.13.05.32.2.39.56.41,1.21.76,1.58,1.39-.82.92-1.93,1.56-3.08,1.9-1.51.45-3.11.1-4.53-.51-.82-.31-1.55-.85-2.41-1.06-.13.76-.04,1.53-.16,2.29-.42,0-.86.06-1.27-.05-.09-.28-.08-.57-.11-.86-.12-1.7-.12-3.41,0-5.11.02-.32.07-.63.14-.94.39-.03.79-.04,1.18,0,.22.86.21,1.75.22,2.63.6-.23,1.09-.7,1.69-.95.55-.24,1.15-.31,1.74-.39.37-.06.66-.35.86-.66.31-.47.66-.93.85-1.47-.15.04-.33.03-.43.16-.35.36-.6.81-.99,1.13-.22.19-.53.17-.8.14.18-1.03.64-1.98,1.06-2.93.45-.9.84-1.85,1.5-2.6m-5.5,7.62c0,.36-.01.71-.01,1.07,1.07-.12,2.14-.08,3.21,0-.05-.04-.15-.13-.2-.17-1-.3-2.11-.27-3-.9Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m49.01,78.96c.04-.23.22-.49.47-.45.29.04.65,0,.89.2.35,1.07.17,2.22.21,3.33.03,1-.1,1.99-.1,2.98,0,.24-.07.46-.12.69-.36.13-.75.13-1.13.11-.06-.06-.13-.13-.19-.19-.17-1.01-.25-2.03-.19-3.06.03-1.21-.06-2.44.16-3.64Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m51.16,78.62c.37-.07.76-.08,1.14-.03.14.3.13.65.17.98.04,1.27.15,2.53.05,3.8-.05.7-.01,1.42-.2,2.11-.04.09-.05.24-.17.25-.33.12-.67.03-1-.01-.3-1.24-.17-2.52-.22-3.79.06-1.1-.15-2.26.23-3.31Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
      <path d="m47.14,78.66c.38-.1.78-.03,1.16.01.24.66.2,1.37.19,2.06.02.99,0,1.97,0,2.96.02.72.03,1.46-.24,2.14-.32,0-.65.04-.97-.02-.2-.18-.18-.49-.23-.73-.17-1.59-.18-3.19-.08-4.79.02-.55.05-1.1.18-1.63Z" style="fill: #032e38;"/>
    </g>
  </g>

<defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
/* переворот стороны при наведении курсора мыши */
.flip-container:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.flip-container, .logo {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
     -moz-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
}

/* переворот стороны при наведении курсора мыши */
.flip-container:hover .flipper,  
.flip-container.hover .flipper  {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.logo, .front, .back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
          transition: 0.9s;

  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center;
}

/* скрывает обратную сторону во время переворота */
.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* размещение лицевой стороны над обратной */
.front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 4;
}

/* скрывает, изначально, обратную сторону */
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
          transform: rotateY(90deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
]]>
</style>
</defs>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

- изменил шрифт и ввёл символы на латинице, т.к. в разных браузерах буква «Л» отображалась некорректно. пришлось использовать перевёрнутую латинскую «V»;
- добавил параметры для кроссбраузерности;
- заменил «лаврушку»;

В отличии от изначального варианта, отсутствует эффект от perspective
Смена стороны достигается мгновенно за счёт hover (когда убирается курсор - видно, что лицевая сторона .front не скрывается

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip вроде бы этот эффект готовый...просто скопипастите его

Comment: Другими словами видимая часть и не видимая должна быть в разных div а не в разных группах

Comment: @MonkeyMutant как раз код из этого примера и был взят за основу. Задача сделать всё внутри SVG.

Comment: Добавил Вариант №2, но уж очень он «кривой» мягко говоря...

Comment: Я же написал в разных div а не в разных g

Comment: Если раньше не поможет ктото, я в субботу или в пятницу ближе к прлуночи посмотрю что не работает и почему

Comment: [https://codepen.io/vsredov/pen/mdQXYje] - это самый первый вариант. Всё было нормально, до момента введения параметра transform-origin А потом понеслось...

Comment: Подозреваю, что с моим svg что-то не так... Для наглядности поставил рядом другое изображение ( у обоих одинаковые параметры анимации блика). На моём svg полный отказ действий((( [https://jsbin.com/fadirem/edit?html,output]

Comment: Перспектива и з-индэкс в свг нету, свг это 2д движок ...3д трансформации не возможны и по этому надо те элементы которые надо скрыть помещать в другой блок div а не в группу g

Comment: что то вроде этого ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyQmOjB

Comment: Доброго времени суток, @MonkeyMutant - мои знания css и svg очень малы, но перспектива в svg по всей видимости есть. Это можно увидеть если изменить её значение (со 100px и в меньшую сторону) в примере из моего вопроса (или тут - [https://jsbin.com/fadirem/edit?html,output]). Как раз такого результата и хотелось бы достигнуть (естественно, чтобы отображались обе стороны)

Comment: перспективы нету в svg - спорить не буду ...

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, ни в коем случае не собираюсь спорить с Вами.  Всего лишь хочу достигнуть правильного переворота, как тут: [jsbin.com/fadirem/edit?html,output], (только с отображением обоих сторон).

Comment: [https://jsbin.com/godejez/edit?html,output] - вот оно! не знаю с чем это связано, но изменение значения перспективы в стиле css этого svg - работает. осталось понять, как заставить работать linearGradient и будет сказочно))) благоДарю Вам за внимание и желание помочь!